# JS - if I first run search (highlight text) then .click on section doesn't wanna work

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I run search and highlight text:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        highlightSearch();
    }
});

function highlightSearch() {

    $('span').removeClass('highlighted');
    var text = document.getElementById("query").value;
    var query = new RegExp("(\\b" + text + "\\b(?!([^<]+)?>))", "gim");
    var e = document.getElementById("searchText").innerHTML;
    var enew = e.replace(/(<span class='highlighted'>|<\/span>)/igm, "");
    document.getElementById("searchText").innerHTML = enew;
    var newe = enew.replace(query, "<span class='highlighted'>$1</span>");
    document.getElementById("searchText").innerHTML = newe;

}
```

then this part of code stop working:

```
$('.service-box').click(function(){                    
    $('#siteOverlay').addClass('overlay-active');
    $('#popupWindow').addClass('service-active');
    $('#popupWindow #contentBox').html($(this).html());
});
```

It doesn't register .click() anymore.  I can not find out what is wrong. Can You please help me resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Btw: You should always escape the query value first.

Comment: What Do You mean by escape query value first?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646142/what-does-it-mean-to-escape-a-string

Comment: Oh, You mean quotation marks around query are not escaped. So, when used as variable text there could be a quotation marks conflict?

Comment: If you can provide me a working fiddle with your code I could give you an example of what I mean.

Comment: It's ok, thanks. I will probably going to use your plugin anyway.

Comment: It's definitely saver. If I'm seeing it correctly, you don't ignore highlighting inside HTML tag names or `<script>` or `<style>` tags too. For example when you are trying to highlight "span" it could break the code when there are `<span>` tags inside your `#searchText`

Comment: I had that problem, it was highlighting html tags and I have resolved that by adding regexp (?!([^<]+)?>))    This excludes everything in between these <> characters.

Comment: I still have one problem and I can not find solution. When I click search for some reason existing div becomes wrapped with existing span.  I have created a JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/denisbotic/vwph38gy/10/

Comment: Well, you are removing all `</span>` tags from the innerHTML in `var enew`, also the `</span>` of `.glyphicon`. Therefore the element becomes wrapped. Furthermore an exception is thrown: `ReferenceError: highlightSearch is not defined`. Again, to make it right and to save time, I'd recommend to use an existing plugin. Have a look at [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-text-highlighter-plugins/) comparing the popular ones.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen this article few days ago and I will use it. But I am still learning and therefore I like to know what is causing that problem.

Comment: Have a look at my answer on your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/37568893/3894981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `innerHTML` and **getting rid of all the event handlers**. If you are going to use it, please delegate the events:

```
$(document).on("click", '.service-box', function(){                    
  $('#siteOverlay').addClass('overlay-active');
  $('#popupWindow').addClass('service-active');
  $('#popupWindow #contentBox').html($(this).html());
});
```

Since I don't know what's the static parent, I have used `document`. Please replace it with a selector for a static parent instead.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's not working is because you are using `innerHTML` for the highlighting, which destroys events of that element and also trigger generation of the DOM over and over again.

Because of this and [more reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343967/3894981) I've developed [mark.js](https://markjs.io/), a keyword highlighter for search terms or custom regular expressions.

Comment: Just delegate the events. Why a library for this?

Comment: Because it's evil! As I said, this also triggers re-generation of the DOM over and over again.

Comment: Agreed that the OP's function is evil. Okay.

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/advertising).

Comment: @Tunaki Please explain to me what is wrong with this answer? It gives a constructive explanation why it doesn't work and gives an alternative to this.

Comment: @julmot It appears you are the developer of this library, thus you need to give disclosure of that. (which I see has been done by a moderator now).

Comment: @julmot It's expected that you give full disclosure when you offer products and/or open source projects you are endorsed with, like the one I edited in for you. Please remember to do this in the future. Self promotion is something the community is very sensitive about.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha What exactly do you mean by "disclosure"? The code given by the OP isn't enough for me to present a running demo, as he missed the HTML part.

Comment: "disclosure" meaning that you clearly state that it's a library you actively develop, and have ties with. I don't want to have this discussion in the comments. If it's still unclear for you, please ask on [meta].

Comment: Updated answer to reflect that I'm the core developer.

Comment: Thank You guys!  Praveen Kumar and Julmot have answered my question. .click is working now as Praven Kumar has suggested. There are also other things that I didn't think of like iframes which could be used in the future. Thanks to Julmot I am aware of this now. I will mark Praveen Kumar answer as correct one.