# On search/highlight click -> existing div becomes wrapped with existing span

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, full-text-search, highlight

I have a problem with javascript search and highlight text.
For example, there is existing span element and existing div element.
Problem is that if I click on search button for some reason div element becomes a child of span element.

To explain it better I have created JS fiddle to show the problem:

```
function highlightSearch() {

    $('span').removeClass('highlighted');
    var text = document.getElementById('query').value;
    var query = new RegExp("(\\b" + text + "\\b(?!([^<]+)?>))", "gim");
    var e = document.getElementById("searchText").innerHTML;
    var enew = e.replace(/(<span class='highlighted'>|<\/span>)/igm, "");
    document.getElementById("searchText").innerHTML = enew;
    var newe = enew.replace(query, "<span class='highlighted'>$1</span>");
    document.getElementById("searchText").innerHTML = newe;
}
```

Check problem on : [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/denisbotic/vwph38gy/10/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are removing all `</span>` tags from the `innerHTML` in this line:

```
var enew = e.replace(/(<span class='highlighted'>|<\/span>)/igm, "");
```

And therefore also the `</span>` of `.glyphicon`. This is why the element becomes wrapped.

Btw: An exception is thrown: `ReferenceError: highlightSearch is not defined`